# Save data received from an online csv file into Core Data with Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift2

I am kinda new to Swift. So I am trying to import this upload a csv file which contains a list of English words with their corresponding translations in Chinese and Thai. I have created a csv parser in AppDelegate, and the data is being displayed using print. However, I am not able to save the data in Coredata entity. I have a simple Core Data entity called Words, with columns englishwords, chinesewords, thaiwords.

Here is my code:

```
func preloadData () {

    // Remove all the menu items before preloading
    //removeData()

    var error:NSError?
    let remoteURL = NSURL(string: "http://dethink.co/words.csv")!
    let wordsFromCsv = parseCSV(remoteURL, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &error)


    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext


    for word in  wordsFromCsv! {
        var new_word = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName ("Words", inManagedObjectContext: context ) as NSManagedObject

    .......

   }
  }
```

What do I do next on this?

Comment: it would be good to see what is in "word" in the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing that your data looks like this:

```
mango,èŠ’æžœ,à¸¡à¸°à¸¡à¹ˆà¸§à¸‡
apple,è‹¹æžœ,à¹à¸­à¸›à¹€à¸›à¸´à¹‰à¸¥
banana,é¦™è•‰,à¸à¸¥à¹‰à¸§à¸¢
milk,ç‰›å¥¶,à¸™à¸¡
water,æ°´,à¸™à¹‰à¸³
tea,èŒ¶,à¸Šà¸²
coffee,å’–å•¡,à¸à¸²à¹à¸Ÿ
eat,åƒ,à¸à¸´à¸™
drink,å–,à¸”à¸·à¹ˆà¸¡
see,è§,à¹€à¸«à¹‡à¸™
sit,å,à¸™à¸±à¹ˆà¸‡
stand,ç«™,à¸¢à¸·¸™
```

And assuming that your `parseCSV` function (which you did not share) returns an array of arrays (`[[String]]`) - and assuming that you have generated a `NSManagedObject` subclass called `Word`, you can populate in the loop as follows:

```
var newWord = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Words", 
              inManagedObjectContext: context ) as! Word
newWord.string = word[0] as? String
newWord.firstWeirdString = word[1] as? String
newWord.secondWeirdString = word[2] as? String
```

Save outside the loop. Obviously you will presumably have more meaningful attribute name in your `Word` class.

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to know more info, expecially what is your CSV data structure, but basicly you need to do:

```
// associate the values from your csv to the word istance
    new_word.englishwords = word.english
    new_word.chinesewords = word.chinese
    new_word.thaiwords = word.thaiwords

// end of for loop
```

at the end save your context:

```
do {
       try context.save()
   } catch {
       print("Unresolved error")
 }
```